# ng-click not triggering a controller function on a table td click which is rendered later after the controller is initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I want to trigger a function in a controller (initialized on page load) called on ng-click present on a td element of table which is loaded after selecting some option from the select box in the HTML page.

Using ui-router, i am loading an HTML page with its controller on click of a menu item. This HTML contains a form with a combo box (select tag) with some options in it. Also i have a div which is container for a  table and the div is empty to on page load. When some option is selected from the combo box, i have a custom directive which executes the change event and inside the container div, a table is created using pure JavaScript and loaded with data received from an Ajax call. The TDs in this table have a ng-click present on them which should trigger a function present in the controller which is not happening. I am new to AngularJS and hence any help received will be appreciated.

I have tried using $digest, $apply on the $scope variable (inside JavaScript's setTimeout function) inside the custom directive after the table is rendered. But the changes didn't apply.

HTML code

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ui-view>
<div id="mainContainer" align="center">
    <form name="form1" id="formWithSelect" ng-init="loadSelectList()">
        <div align="left">
            <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 1.30em;">Please select an option to fetch list.</p>
        </div>
        <div align="left" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <label class="align_label">Select Option :</label> <select
                name="listItems"
                ng-model="listInfo.id" id="list_of_options"
                get-list=""
                data-enhance="false"
                ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in listItems required><option
                    value="">Select Item</option></select>
            <p ng-if="form1.listItems.$dirty && form1.listItems.$error.required" class="invalidMessage">Select Item</p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="tableContainer"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

AngularJS Code

```
var tableApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router','uiRouterStyles','flow']);
tableApp.controller("ListCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.loadSelectList = function(){
        $scope.listItems = manager.getListItems();
    };

    $scope.getItemInfo = function(event){
        alert("Need a pop up!!!");
        event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);
    };
});

tableApp.directive("getList", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope,elm) {
            elm.on('change', function (ev){
               if(ev.currentTarget.value == ""){
                   $("#tableContainer").css("display","none").empty();
                }
                else{
                    $("#tableContainer").empty();
                    manager.getTableData();
                    tableDataView.viewTable();
                }
               setTimeout(function() {
                   $scope.$digest();
               }, 1000);
               ev.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
});

UI router

.state('change-table-data', {
            url: '/change/table/data',
            templateUrl: 'ChangeTable.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl',
            data: {
                  css: ['stylesheet1.css','stylesheet2.css']
                }
        })
```

Expected output

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ui-view>
<div id="mainContainer" align="center">
    <form name="form1" id="formWithSelect" ng-init="loadSelectList()">
        <div align="left">
            <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 1.30em;">Please select an option to fetch list.</p>
        </div>
        <div align="left" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <label class="align_label">Select Option :</label> <select
                name="listItems"
                ng-model="listInfo.id" id="list_of_options"
                get-list=""
                data-enhance="false"
                ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in listItems required><option
                    value="">Select Item</option></select>
            <p ng-if="form1.listItems.$dirty && form1.listItems.$error.required" class="invalidMessage">Select Item</p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="tableContainer">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Serial Number</th>
<th>Item ID</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td ng-click="getItemInfo($event)">1</td>
<td ng-click="getItemInfo($event)">I101</td>
<td ng-click="getItemInfo($event)">ABC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-click="getItemInfo($event)">2</td>
<td ng-click="getItemInfo($event)">I102</td>
<td ng-click="getItemInfo($event)">XYZ</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As shown above in the Expected output section, a table is rendered and each td has ng-click function over it. On click of this td, i need the getItemInfo() present in the controller to trigger which is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to pass $compile service to

> **getList** directive

and inside the directive instead of

```
setTimeout(function() {
                   $scope.$digest();
               }, 1000);
```

function, it should have been

```
setTimeout(function() {
                       $compile($("#tableContainer"))($scope);
                   }, 1000);
```

I am now able to trigger the controller function

> **getItemInfo**